# pyswmm installation on MacOS fails

Tags: python, installation, conda, pyswmm

On my MacBook Pro (Apple M1 - MacOS 12.5.1 Monterey), I try to install pyswmm but always get an error. In my `hydro` conda environment (with python 3.11 installed but I also tried with 3.8) I do the following:

`/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/hydro/bin/python -m pip install pyswmm`

but get the error:

```
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/sh/5crwm0kd1rjc0bhslgr4mn440000gq/T/pip-install-omnumz4_/swmm-toolkit_a4bc0bd7a2fa4bc9a5a0487c398ef3f7/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
          from skbuild import setup
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
```

So I tried to install in this same environment scikit-build (success) before running the command a second time. Now I get the error:

```
      running egg_info
      creating /private/var/folders/sh/5crwm0kd1rjc0bhslgr4mn440000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ny3x3dqn/swmm_toolkit.egg-info
      writing /private/var/folders/sh/5crwm0kd1rjc0bhslgr4mn440000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ny3x3dqn/swmm_toolkit.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/sh/5crwm0kd1rjc0bhslgr4mn440000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ny3x3dqn/swmm_toolkit.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to /private/var/folders/sh/5crwm0kd1rjc0bhslgr4mn440000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ny3x3dqn/swmm_toolkit.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/sh/5crwm0kd1rjc0bhslgr4mn440000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ny3x3dqn/swmm_toolkit.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/sh/5crwm0kd1rjc0bhslgr4mn440000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ny3x3dqn/swmm_toolkit.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      error: package directory 'lib' does not exist
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You can get it through Conda Forge once the `swmm` package is built for **osx-arm64**. The directions are here: https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#apple-silicon-builds. Basically, add `swmm` to the end of [this file](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/blob/main/recipe/migrations/osx_arm64.txt), submit that as a PR, and it will trigger Conda Forge to start building `swmm` for **osx-arm64**.